# React material-ui KeyboardDatePicker and Formik not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup

I'm creating a form with `material-ui` and I'm using `Formik` and `Yup` for validation.

The TextField components work perfectly, however, **the `KeyboardDatePicker` component presented the following error in the console**

> _onChange is not a function

and is now presenting

> type is undefined.

Below is a cbs with the code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dust-wf6fn

Comment: I run your code but did not see that error. I however saw other types of error with `findDOMNode`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use `.setFieldValue` to set value manually on `onChange` event.

```
 onChange={val => {
      console.log("___", val);
      formik.setFieldValue("dob", val);
 }}
```

this method will work in any usecase.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Why doesn't this component work with Formik's handleChange? It is necessary to define an own

Comment: handleChange relies on e.target.name , which in case of datePicker doesn't work.

Comment: e.target will always be undefined in DatePicker

Comment: Interesting. Thank you

Comment: This is what I already have. I wanted to spread the field like I do into inputs and selects, and the onChange is set that way. I'm finding with MUI DateTimePicker I have to do just as this answer suggests. I just don't know why I can't get a good onChange when I `const [field, meta] = formik.useField(id);` and then spread in field (which includes a unworking onChange) to the `<DateTimePicker {...field}`? I mean because this works with every other input type in my app.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sand box demo for the same

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-material-ui-date-picker-with-yup-validate-f3mdp